# LINQ query stops working after adding 'Orderby' clause

Tags: c#, linq, uwp

I have a working linq query as follows:

```cs
public static List<Coins> GetAllCoins(string typeselected)
{
    using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DbPath))
    {
        List<Coins> allcoins = (from p in db.Table<Coins>()
                    where p.CoinType== typeselected
                    // orderby p.YearMinted
                    select p
                ).ToList();
        return allcoins;
    }
}
```

I want to get the results in order but when I uncomment the 'orderby' line, the query returns nothing.  What's up with that?

I have checked the syntax many times.  I have queried online for linq query format and I find many instances where the orderby clause is used in this manner.  I know I'm missing something but I can't figure what.  Please help!

Comment: what is the datatype of `YearMinted`

Comment: This is not linq only, this is about linq to entities which is ef! If your query provider is not EF, please update the tags accordingly and remove entity-framework again :)

Comment: YearMinted is int.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying now, Mafii.  I don't know how that ef tag got there.  I am going to try to remove it.

Comment: I think `YearMinted ` is `null` for the records. Can you check that and if yes then do something like `orderby p.YearMinted ?? 0`

Comment: I'd agree with an entry of `YearMinted` being `null` for at least one record. place a `try...catch` block to catch a possible exception

Comment: No reasonable implementation of order by can change the number of results returned (in this case to 0), be it in database or in memory, nulls do not matter either. So it's something else going here.

Comment: vivek nuna, thanks for your help.  But I opened the database using DBrowser and checked all the records have a YearMinted, a four digit integer.  Curiously, when the typeselected is one with only one record, it does return that one record but any instances where more than one coin meets the typeselected, nothing is retuned.

Comment: Although a close examination of my database Table, coins, reveals no null YearMinted, I do conclude that the issue is something to do with the data.  The database is old and was created several years ago.  I created a new database adding only about ten records and the query does work with the orderby on the new database.  It apparently has to do with how the data was recorded in the older database and the reason is above my pay grade.  : )  I am going to attempt to import the old data into a newly created database.

Comment: I was able to avoid the problem by sorting the list after it is retrieved by adding this line of code:

allcoins.Sort(delegate (Coins x, Coins y) { return x.YearMinted.CompareTo(y.YearMinted);});